# How can I count the number of whitespace characters in a file?

Tags: wc, whitespace

I wanted to count the number of whitespace characters in a file.  The best I could come up with was:

```
tr -cd [:space:] < my_file | wc
```

Is there a neater way?

Comment: Do you want to count newlines as well ?

Comment: @User112638726 yes please

Comment: Also what exactly do you mean by neater ?

Comment: @User112638726 e.g. just counting the characters.  my solution deletes everything else and then counts what's left - seems a bit indirect to me

Comment: You could use `awk -vRS='[[:space:]]' 'END{print NR}'` or `awk -vRS= '{print gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"&")}'` but that probably looks worse. For your other command you may want to use `wc -c` to prevent the line and word counts coming up as well.

Comment: @Alison - your method might seem indirect, but I don't think that's the case. No matter how you do this task, you have to have a program that examines every character (every byte) in the file. There's no short cuts for that I can see. "Deleting" isn't really the case, as `tr` actually just passes all whitespace characters down the pipe. It's just selective about what characters it passes, rather than "deleting" anything.

Comment: In GNU `tr` `tr -cd [:space:] < my_file | wc -c` is neater in the sense that it will output just the number of whitespaces, while `tr -cd [:space:] < my_file | wc` will output the number of lines, words and characters tab-separated.

Answer (score 5):

```
tr -cd '[:space:]' < my_file | wc -m
```

Would work. But with GNU `tr`, that would only work in single byte per character locales (typically, not in UTF-8 ones) or with ASCII only input in UTF-8 locales.

Without the quotes around `[:space:]`, you'd get an error message in csh, tcsh or zsh (unless the condition below is met) and in most shells, that would fail if there was a file called `:`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c` or `e` in the current directory as `[:space:]` is a shell glob.

Also note that `wc` doesn't count characters by default (it's bytes, words and newlines only when not given any option).

With GNU `awk` you can use:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' 'END{print NR}'
```

Example:

```
$ printf '\0\u2006\t\r\n' | awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' 'END{print NR}'
4
```

(for the U+2006 *SIX-PER-EM SPACE*, TAB, CR and NL characters which are all classified as whitespace in my locale).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

file=`cat $1`

length=`cat $1 | wc -m` // Count the charater
count=0
for ((i = 0 ;i < $length;i++)) do //loop to the end of the string

    if [ "${file:$i:1}" == "$2" ] //Look only character by character (select some characters of the String, (:$i:1) is the range of the choosen characters
    then
        count=$((count + 1))

    fi
done    
echo $count

//test.txt = "Is there a neater way?"
#./CountChar test.txt " "
>>> 4
```

it's an "other" way..x), hope you like it !